# Why is my image not showing up in html (I am very new to it)

Tags: html

I am playing around with HTML and I am trying to add and image but when I run it the it does not show.

[Here Is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThIsL.jpg)

I am very new to HTML so don't judge...

Comment: You have a typo in your <img>. Run your HTML thru a validator first when things mysteriously don't work; this error would immediately show up.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the spelling of the src property. you typed "SCR". please change that to src and it will work. `<img src="IMG_0901.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

check you img tag
it should be `<img src="IMG_0901.jpg">` not `<img scr="IMG_0901.jpg">`

your code has typo error "scr" attributes